# How to render a partial view on click in link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table with information and I want to click on link (which is a  bootstrap gliphycon), when I click on this link I want to render a partial view inside a bootstrap modal with all information about this list item.

My controller

```
public PartialViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                return PartialView("Details", _paisRepository.GetDetails(id));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ViewBag.error = "Não foi possivel buscar os dados!";
                return PartialView("Error");
            }
        }
```

I call action method that returns data to modal that way:

```
<a href="/Pais/Details/@item.ID">
   <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="cursor:pointer"></div>
</a>
```

and the bootstrap modal

```
<div class="modal" id="exibirPais" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    <label class="control-label">Exibir</label>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                @Html.Partial()

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need ajax to call the server method that returns the partial and update the DOM in its success callback.

Comment: This post explains the solution for exact use case. [MVC - Html.Action to retrieve element using Javascript, then pass it as parameter to Controller, then return a PartialView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39865095/40521)

Comment: I read your post @Shyju and I will not use Html.partial to render the partial view, I will use my javascript function?

Comment: your js code makes an ajax call to your action method which returns a partial view result (ultimately pure HTML) and use that to the modal dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:

Add a javascript function call to your glyphicon and send the current object item ID

```
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="cursor:pointer" data- onclick="ShowDetails('@item.id')"></span>
```

Change your Modal to something this:

```
<div class="modal" id="exibirPais" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                <label class="control-label">Exibir</label>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="Body">
         @*  Body where the  partial view will be rendered using AJAX*@

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Fechar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Your javascript function :

```
 function ShowDetails(Id) {
        $("#exibirPais").modal();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Controller/Details/' + Id,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#Body').html(result);

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the click event on this a tags and use ajax to make a request to the server action method and use the response coming back to build the modal dialog.

So in your main view, when you render the a tag, you can set the href value as the url path to the action method.

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in SomeCollection)
{
  <tr>
     <td>
         <a href="@Url.Action("Details",new {id=item.Id})" class="modal-link">
                     <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="cursor:pointer"></div>
         </a>
     </td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

We added a css class `modal-link` to the anchor tags. Now let's add listen to the click event on the anchor tag (With this css class), make tan ajax call to the href value of the clicked link. When the ajax method returns the result (the html markup generated by action method), we will use that as the modal dialog content.

```
$(function() {    

     $('body').on('click', '.modal-link',function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         $("#myModal").remove();

         $.get($(this).attr("href"),function (data) {
               $('<div id="myModal" class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog" 
                                                                    role="document">' +
                            data +'</div></div>').modal();
         });
     });

})
```

This code will replace the entire content of the modal with the partial view result coming from the `Details` action method. That means [you need to include the necessary markup needed for the modal header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39417559/40521)(with buttons) in the `Details.cshtml` partial view.

Answer (score 0):

by click event in javascript

```
 $("#exibirPais").load('@Url.Action("PartialViewResult", "Controller_Name")');
```

N.B.: PartialViewResult must return PartialView(model);
and .cshtml page a partial page